# LaTeX not referencing manual bibliograghy

Tags: bibliographies

All citings of manual bibliography turn into question marks.

```
Show how bibliography works.  The describtion of bibliography is at \url{https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management}. The exam-ple refference here \cite{latexBasics} is the book about \LaTeX{}.

Example how to cite book found on Google Books. This book \cite{C functions} describes the secrets of functional programming using C\#.
\begin{thebibliography}{2}
\bibitem{latexBasics}
Leslie Lamport,
\textit{\LaTeX:  document preparation system,}
Addison Wesley, Massachusetts, 2nd edition, 1994

\bibitem{C functions}
Anggoro, W.,
\textit{Functional C\#}
, Packt Publishing, isbn: 9781785881039,2016. URL:https://books.google.cz/books?id=O9DcDgAAQBAJ
\end{thebibliography}
```

[image: Citings with question marks]

Comment: did you compile enough times? And better don't use spaces and other unusual chars in the bibitem.

Comment: Its my first time using LaTeX because of school, this was written on latexbase.com if that helps. I will try shortening the keys, but doubt that will help, since not even the first book gets referenced.

Comment: when I put your code in a small document it works fine after the second compilation.

Comment: latexbase.com compliles on the fly, as much as I know and I have been trying to get it working for a few hours now. Is there some package that I am not using that I should be?

Comment: I can't know if you are missing some package (but your document needs hyperref). But if you would missing it, you should get errors. If latexbase doesn't show you them, then perhaps look for better online editor. Try learnlatex.org, or overleaf.

Comment: This is only a part of my whole document, I have got hyperref package, but surprisingly ,getting a package that would assist better with bibliography would be the subject that results in errors.`! LaTeX Error: File bibtex.sty not found.`

Comment: I know that it is not your whole document, it wouldn't compile as it is. But I can't know what you are doing in the rest of your document. If you want help you will have to learn to make complete examples. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: Would posting the entire code be a good enough example?

Comment: depends how long it is.  minimal examples should be complete, but small. So better remove unneeded stuff.

Comment: After omiting other uneeded sections, here is the rest of the info that could help.

`\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}

\title{Quick start with \LaTeX{}}

\author{My name}
\date{29/10/2020}

\begin{document}
\maketitle`

Comment: Edit your question.

Comment: [LaTeXbase](//latexbase.com) doesn't seem to offer multiple compilations, so your `\cite`s won't resolve to the appropriate reference. Consider using something like [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) instead if an online editor is all you can manage.